# Inverter output goes to 0V when transformer is attached

Tags: arduino, power, pwm, power-electronics, inverter

I am making a 5 level inverter using an Arduino Mega and I am getting about 18V AC output from the circuit given below.

The problem is when I attach a transformer the output goes to 0V.  I don't know why this is happening can anyone please help me.

I am using two 5V adapters with boost converters to give power to the circuit.

This is the exact circuit I am using:
[image]

This is my arduino code:

```
    float f=50;
    float t=(1/f)*1000000;
    float a1=10;
    float a2=40;
    float a1p1=(a1*t)/360;
    float a1p2=(a2*t)/360;
    float d=5;

    int pin1=1;
    int pin2=2;
    int pin3=3;
    int pin4=4;
    int pin5=5;
    int pin6=6;
    int pin7=7;
    int pin8=8;

    void setup() {
      Serial.begin(9600);
      pinMode(pin1, OUTPUT);
      pinMode(pin2, OUTPUT);
      pinMode(pin3, OUTPUT);
      pinMode(pin4, OUTPUT);
      pinMode(pin5, OUTPUT);
      pinMode(pin6, OUTPUT);
      pinMode(pin7, OUTPUT);
      pinMode(pin8, OUTPUT);
    }

    void loop(){
      digitalWrite(pin1,HIGH);
      digitalWrite(pin2,HIGH);
      digitalWrite(pin5,HIGH);
      digitalWrite(pin6,HIGH);
      delayMicroseconds(a1p1-d);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   

      digitalWrite(pin2, LOW);
      delayMicroseconds(d);
      digitalWrite(pin4,HIGH);
      delayMicroseconds(a1p2-a1p1-d);

      digitalWrite(pin6,LOW);
      delayMicroseconds(d);
      digitalWrite(pin8,HIGH);
      delayMicroseconds(t/2-(2*a1p2)-d);

      digitalWrite(pin5,LOW);
      delayMicroseconds(d);
      digitalWrite(pin7,HIGH);
      delayMicroseconds(a1p2-a1p1-d);

      digitalWrite(pin1,LOW);
      delayMicroseconds(d);
      digitalWrite(pin3,HIGH);
      delayMicroseconds((2*a1p1)-d);

      digitalWrite(pin4,LOW);
      delayMicroseconds(d);
      digitalWrite(pin2,HIGH);
      delayMicroseconds(a1p2-a1p1-d);

      digitalWrite(pin8,LOW);
      delayMicroseconds(d);
      digitalWrite(pin6,HIGH);
      delayMicroseconds(t/2-(2*a1p2)-d);

      digitalWrite(pin7,LOW);
      delayMicroseconds(d);
      digitalWrite(pin5,HIGH);
      delayMicroseconds(a1p2-a1p1-d);

      digitalWrite(pin3,LOW);
      delayMicroseconds(d);
      digitalWrite(pin1,HIGH);
      delayMicroseconds(a1p1);
    }
```

Comment: It could be that your supplies are in short circuit protection mode.

Comment: It looks like your upper NMOS switches will be really poor in conduction i.e. they'll never fully switch on.

Comment: i am  getting around 6 - 6.7 volt at gate of upper mosfets @Andy aka